# how to add API NSArray to tableViewCell in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM2fD.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EOuS.png)

I'm new to objective c and I get an array like this " [https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM2fD.png[enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM2fD.png%5Benter) image description here][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EOuS.png) " via the API and I can't compare all the elements in the array to labels like "monthLabel" "vsumLabel" "summaLabel" "fsumLabel" that I created in the cell called (grafigCell) " https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EOuS.png ". please help

Comment: Copy/paste content rather that only images, and I didn't understand what's supposed to be the expected output. Could you clarify?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.